# Disable two finger scrolling everywhere there isn't a scrollbar!

Tags: mouse, lxde, scrolling

I love two-finger scrolling, but if my mouse cursor is slightly in the wrong place, it will activate the wrong feature -- features that I never use!

If the cursor is over the titlebar, it will scroll through tabs.

If the cursor is on my 'start bar'/LXpanel. It will scroll through windows.

If the cursor happens to be on a pixel related to the desktop, it will scroll through workspaces.

I never need to scroll through these elements. Does anyone know how I could disable those features?

I am using LXDE.

Comment: You could be more specific about the scrolling through tabs part. Does it happen with Firefox tabs?  Does it happen with LXTerminal tabs?

Comment: Note that the way two-finger scrolling works is that the touchpad sends mouse wheel events, which are encoded as button presses (buttons 4 and 5). So if there's an interface to configure this, it's probably worded in terms of mouse wheel, not in terms of two-finger scrolling.